# Java - Replace a specific string sequence

Tags: java, string

I got a string `x` with a value. There, I want to replace a sequence of `xx111159` as `idno` where xx can be anything but it must be replaced. Other chars remain the same.

**Example:** `ab111159ab` as `idnoab` and `cd111159` as `idno`.

Is there a way for this to be done with Replace funct? I know a way that would need to check if the last chars is `111159` but that would cause to read the whole string one by one char...

Comment: Is this safe to assume that the string will always start with `xx111159`? Whats would you expect as a result if the string contains only `111159` i.e. it start with 111159 without any char in front of the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular expression and `String.replaceAll()` you can accomplish your goal:

```
String result = x.replaceAll(".{2}111159", "idno");
```

Where `.` matches any character and `{2}` ensures there's two characters before `111159`.

Comment: plus 1 because you explained the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex and replace

```
 str = str.replaceAll(".{2}111159","idno")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
x = x.replaceAll(".{2}111159", "idno");
```